# Showing a set of articles in UIWebview from REST api call that has start and limit parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I want to show a set of articles with intro text from a website into a UIWebview. The REST api is already done.

The REST api method takes the following form to retrieve a set of articles :
          http://example.com/articles?start=0&limit=10

"start" and "limit" parameters are optional and if not supplied, the REST api takes default values of 0 and 10 for start and limit parameters respectively.

I have retrieved the first 10 articles and displayed them into the UIWebview.

When the user scrolls to the the bottom of the UIWebview, I want to load next 10 articles, i.e., I want to fire the following query and display the result in the web view :

http://example.com/articles?start=11&limit=10

But, I am not being able to achieve that.

I am new in IOS programming and could not find any help regarding this subject. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your own subclass of UIWebView. This class implements the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, and these precisely are the methods you will have to override in such child class. Have a look to the UIScrollViewDelegate reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)

For example, you might wanna implement `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate`

and track the `contentOffset` property of the `scrollView` parameter. 
When it reaches a certain threshold, you can retrieve more content from your API increasing start and limit accordingly and feed it to your webview. This would be a ver simple lazy loading technique for your webview.